# Debug application

Tags: android-studio, debugging

I have a confusing problem. I wanted to send email automatically from my program for that I added three jar library file to libs folder. When I added activation.jar lib file, I could not find 'add as library' for adding lib to gradle and for that I added this manually. Anyway, now when I want to debug my application from run menu, I see  debug "activation.jar" instead of seeing my program name! I want run or debug my application but I can't because I see activation.jar !

Why did this happen and how can solve this?

I tried deleting the jar file and resetting android studio but that didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Share you app build.gradle. If there is no following line _compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])_ put it there and build your app.

Comment: You can change the active run/debug configuration on the top right side of your IDE somewhere, or click on "Edit Configurations.." in your context menu.